# Why does C++ reject appending a structure to a binary file if it contains a member of the string class?

Tags: c++

So today I made almost no progress programming because I very slowly realized that C++ is a very type-cased sensitive language in the respect that I cannot append a structure to a binary file if one of the members of the structure is of type string class. I had no idea this was the case until I found out. I will prove my point first.

This code will not work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// function Headers:
void Receive_Information(fstream& personal_data);
void Display_Information(fstream& personal_data);

struct Info
{
    string name; // if this is char name[50]; ... it works perfectly.
    float weight;
    char grade;
};

int main()
{
    fstream personal_data;
    // Get two people from the stream:
    Receive_Information(personal_data);
    Receive_Information(personal_data);

    // Now display their information from the binary file.
    Display_Information(personal_data);


    return 0;
}

void Receive_Information(fstream& personal_data)
{
    personal_data.open("personal_data.dat", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary); // open a binary file for appending.

    Info person; // This structure variable is written to the binary file.
    cout << "What is the person's name: ";
    getline(cin, person.name); // change to cin.getline(person.name, 50) when defined as a character array
    cout << "\nWhat is this individual's weight: ";
    cin >> person.weight;
    cout << "\nWhat letter grade (A, B, C, D, F) did s(he) get on the last exam: ";
    cin >> person.grade;

    // write the structure variable to file.
    personal_data.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&person), sizeof(person));

    cin.ignore();

    personal_data.close(); // close the file after writing to it.

    cout << endl;
}

void Display_Information(fstream& personal_data)
{
    Info person_out; // This is the structure variable we get from opening the binary file.

    personal_data.open("personal_data.dat", ios::in | ios::binary); // Open the binary file to read from.

    personal_data.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&person_out), sizeof(person_out)); // Read the first line of the file.

    while(personal_data) // While I haven't reached the end of the file keep reading in the information.
    {
        cout << "The weight of the person is " << person_out.weight << endl;

        cout << "The person's name is " << person_out.name << endl; // This can't be printed because it's a string.

        cout << "The grade this individual received on the last exam is " << person_out.grade << endl;

        personal_data.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&person_out), sizeof(person_out));// keep pulling information from the file.

        cout << endl;
    }

    personal_data.close();
}
```

If I run the program like I intend then I get this output:

```
What is the person's name: Generic Me

What is this individual's weight: 180

What letter grade (A, B, C, D, F) did s(he) get on the last exam: A

What is the person's name: Suspicious You

What is this individual's weight: 200

What letter grade (A, B, C, D, F) did s(he) get on the last exam: C

The weight of the person is 180
The person's name is // it's no coincidence that it fails here. 
Process returned 255 (0xFF)   execution time : 25.193 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Notice that the function Display_Information() is purposely ordered to show the weight first and then the the name which is of type string. I did that to prove my point that the members of the structure can be read from the binary file, but until one of the variables is a string the program aborts.

So my hypothesis is that a structure cannot easily be written to a binary file if one of the members of type string. To prove my point if I change the name to a character array then everything works.

So to get rid of the clutter, I will manually delete the binary file personal_data.dat, and then rerun the program just making these two minor changes ...

I will change

```
struct Info
{
    string name; // if this is char name[50]; ... it works perfectly.
    float weight;
    char grade;
};
```

to this:

```
struct Info
{
    char name[50]; // A character array which can hold about 50 characters. 
    float weight;
    char grade;
};
```

And then in the Receive_Information function I will change this:

```
getline(cin, person.name);
```

to this

```
cin.getline(person.name, 50);
```

And everything will magically work!!
See how it works perfectly!

```
What is the person's name: Generic Me

What is this individual's weight: 180

What letter grade (A, B, C, D, F) did s(he) get on the last exam: A

What is the person's name: Suspicious You

What is this individual's weight: 200

What letter grade (A, B, C, D, F) did s(he) get on the last exam: C

The weight of the person is 180
The person's name is Generic Me
The grade this individual received on the last exam is A

The weight of the person is 200
The person's name is Suspicious You
The grade this individual received on the last exam is C


Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 12.998 s
Press any key to continue.
```

So now that I proved my point about strings in structures, is there anything that can be done (without using characters) to make my original program work with a string data member in a structure when appended to a binary file. By the way, I also found out that my structure variable person can be written to a binary file with a string member and then successfully read, but the moment you try to append more than one structure you program doesn't like you very much. Pretty strange.

Thoughts.

Comment: Read about "serialization". A `std::string` contains a pointer to the string contents, that's (the pointer) what you're saving to your binary file (which is useless).

Comment: `std::string` is a complex structure that keeps a pointer inside (unlike `char[]` array). You can't just save that pointer and read it again, because it will point to garbage (the memory is dynamic and under OS control). The thing you are trying to do is wrong from the begining, don't use `reinterpret_cast` to serialize/deserialize. Actually don't use `reinterpret_cast` at all.

Comment: That line `personal_data.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&person), sizeof(person));` most certainly is not doing what you think it does. Why are you using `write`? And what do you actually think it does?

Comment: I thought that's how you write a structure to a binary file. It has worked for me until I started using a string member in my structure. What should I be doing instead? I'm still a novice .

Comment: @xyz123 That's not how you store structs in a file. Even if your struct doesn't have a pointer inside (like std::string member) the binary representation is compiler, os and even cpu dependent. Just don't. There are several serialization/deserialization techniques, e.g. xml, json, google protobuf. Just pick one that suits you.

Answer (score 4):

Do **NOT** use `reinterpret_cast` for serialization/deserialization or stringification. `reinterpret_cast` is a very dangerous tool that should be used only in very particular situations. The correct way of dealing with your issue is to provide an `operator<<` and an `operator>>` for your `Info` class. Example:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Info& p)
{
    os << name;
    os << weight;
    os << grade;
    return os;
}
```

---

`reinterpret_cast<T>` literally asks the compiler to look at a memory location and act as if it were a `T`. Classes like `std::string` are complicated: they own resources and store pointers to other memory locations inside them. If you attempt to write the bytes of an `std::string` out, you'll get garbage, as your characters are likely not stored with the `std::string` instance itself...

Comment: Woah. That's pretty advanced, but also pretty simple. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

std::string is a class that stores pointers to another memory location where the actual string is stored.  If you write std::string to file, only the bytes representing the pointers is written, not the string itself.